# Why CORS not working despite headers set?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, slim, slim-3

I have an API with Slim3 framework, I have set headers but when I'm sending request from other website from frontend APP to API I got [OPTIONS] 405 Method Not Allowed and request blocked because rule „Same Origin Policy” not allowed to load from ...

I have tried:

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

not working...

```
$app->add(new CorsMiddleware([
    "origin" => ["*"],
    "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "headers.allow" => [],
    "headers.expose" => [],
    "credentials" => false,
    "cache" => 0,
]));
```

Also not working...

Now my middleware.php looking like:

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware;

$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/') {
        // permanently redirect paths with a trailing slash
        // to their non-trailing counterpart
        $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path, 0, -1));

        if($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
            return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri, 301);
        }
        else {
            return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
        }
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
});

$app->add(new CorsMiddleware([
    "origin" => ["*"],
    "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "headers.allow" => [],
    "headers.expose" => [],
    "credentials" => false,
    "cache" => 0,
]));

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);

    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->withheader('Allow', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
});
```

Frontend side just async fuction with fetch:

```
async (formData) => {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl,
        {
            method:'post',
            mode:'cors',
            body:formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            redirect: 'follow'
        });

        return response.json();
    }
```

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to add a preflight "options" route? [CORS](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/24/slim4-cors.html). 2. When your client sends a Authorization header the response has to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true`.

Comment: Hmm I think so... Do you mean like that? `$app->options('/{routes:.+}', ...?`
There is in first code block in my question.

2. I added to slim header that but still not working

Comment: I solve my problem, I had disable on apache server OPTIONS metod, I enabled and Its start working.